# jQuery.replaceAll multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This isn't working for me:

```
$('<span>Something</span><span>Something else</span>').replaceAll('<span>Something New</span><span>Something New Too</span>');
```

How do I replace more than 1 element? Help please.

The elements are on the DOM, so I cannot append them.

Comment: Are you trying to select those elements from the DOM? Or do you actually mean to create them? jQuery's `$` is overloaded with lots of different behavior (perhaps too much).

Comment: Then you probably don't want to do a `replaceAll`. You'd be better off selecting those elements from the DOM, and updating their text content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<span>Something</span><span>Something else</span>')
    .appendTo("body")
    .each(function(){
       $(this).replaceWith("<span>Something New</span>"); 
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/n9a7t/1/).

We're just appending the `span`s to the body and replacing each one with the "Something New" `span`.

Comment: Good idea, but the elements are already on the page, and I cannot append them.

Comment: Then just do `$("span").each(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it backwards.  It goes

```
$(/*New stuff*/).replaceAll(/*The items you're matching against*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your elements are in the DOM, you need to select them, and update their content.

You could replace them entirely, but it really isn't necessary since you're replacing them with identical element types.

HTML

```
<span>Something</span>
<span>Something else</span>
```

js

```
$('span').text(function(i,txt) {
    if( i === 0 ) {
        return "Something new";
    } else if( i === 1 ) {
        return "Something new too";
    } else {
        return txt;
    }
});
```

There are a number of different ways to do it, but here's one. It will update the content of the first two spans it finds.

To know the proper solution, you'll need to provide more information in the question.